# Optimising algorithm for an operation inserting program

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization

The program I have currently takes N numbers and then a goal target. It inserts either "+" or "*" in between the numbers to try reach the goal. If it can reach the goal it will print out the correct operations. 
However the way it finds the answer is by brute force, which is inadequate for a large set of N numbers. My current code is below:

```
public class Arithmetic4{

  private static ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
  private static ArrayList<String> second_line = new ArrayList<String>();
  private static ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  private static ArrayList<String> operations = new ArrayList<String>();
  private static ArrayList<Integer> temp_array = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(sc.hasNextLine()){
      readInput(sc);
    }
  }

  public static void readInput(Scanner sc){
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    input.add(line);
    line = sc.nextLine();
    second_line.add(line);
    dealInput();
  }

  public static void dealInput(){
    String numberS = input.get(0);
    String[] stringNumbers = numberS.split("\\s+");
    for(int i = 0; i < stringNumbers.length; i++){
      String numberAsString = stringNumbers[i];
      numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(numberAsString));
    }

    String orderString = second_line.get(0);
    String[] stringWhatWay = orderString.split("\\s+");
    int target = Integer.parseInt(stringWhatWay[0]);
    char whatway = stringWhatWay[1].charAt(0);

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    whatEquation(numbers, target, whatway);
    long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime; 
    long elapsedMSeconds = elapsedTime / 1;
    System.out.println(elapsedMSeconds);
    numbers.clear();
    input.clear();
    second_line.clear();
  }

  public static void whatEquation(ArrayList<Integer> numbers, int target, char whatway){
    if(whatway != 'L' && whatway != 'N'){
      System.out.println("Not an option");
    }

    if(whatway == 'N'){
      ArrayList<Integer> tempo_array = new ArrayList<Integer>(numbers);
      int count = 0;
      for (int y: numbers) {
        count++;
      }
      count--;

      int q = count;
      calculateN(numbers, target, tempo_array, q);
    }
    if (whatway == 'L'){
      if(numbers.size() == 1){
        System.out.println("L " + numbers.get(0));
      }
      ArrayList<Integer> temp_array = new ArrayList<Integer>(numbers);
      calculateL(numbers, target, temp_array);
    }
  }     

  public static void calculateN(ArrayList<Integer> numbers, int target, ArrayList<Integer> tempo_numbers, int q){
    int sum = 0;
    int value_inc = 0;
    int value_add;
    boolean firstRun = true;
    ArrayList<Character> ops = new ArrayList<Character>();
    ops.add('+');
    ops.add('*');

    for(int i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, q); i++){
      String bin = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
      while(bin.length() < q)
        bin = "0" + bin;

      char[] chars = bin.toCharArray();
      List<Character> oList = new ArrayList<Character> ();
      for(char c: chars){
        oList.add(c);
      }

      ArrayList<Character> op_array = new ArrayList<Character>();
      ArrayList<Character> temp_op_array = new ArrayList<Character>();

      for (int j = 0; j < oList.size(); j++) {
        if (oList.get(j) == '0') {
          op_array.add(j, ops.get(0));
          temp_op_array.add(j, ops.get(0));

        } else if (oList.get(j) == '1') {
          op_array.add(j, ops.get(1));
          temp_op_array.add(j, ops.get(1));              
        }
      }

      sum = 0;

      for(int p = 0; p < op_array.size(); p++){
        if(op_array.get(p) == '*'){
          int multiSum = numbers.get(p) * numbers.get(p+1);
          numbers.remove(p);
          numbers.remove(p);
          numbers.add(p, multiSum);
          op_array.remove(p);
          p -= 1;
        }
      }
      for(Integer n: numbers){
        sum += n;
      }

      if(sum != target){
        numbers.clear();
        for (int t = 0; t < tempo_numbers.size(); t++) {
          numbers.add(t, tempo_numbers.get(t));
        }
      }
      if (sum == target){
        int count_print_symbol = 0;
        System.out.print("N ");

        for(int g = 0; g < tempo_numbers.size(); g++){
          System.out.print(tempo_numbers.get(g) + " ");
          if(count_print_symbol == q){
            break;
          }
          System.out.print(temp_op_array.get(count_print_symbol) + " ");
          count_print_symbol++;
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        return;
      }          
    }
    System.out.println("N is Impossible");
  }     

  public static void calculateL(ArrayList<Integer> numbers, int target, ArrayList<Integer> temp_array){
    int op_count = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int n = (numbers.size() -1);
    boolean firstRun = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, n); i++) {  
      String bin = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
      while (bin.length() < n)
        bin = "0" + bin;
      char[] chars = bin.toCharArray();
      char[] charArray = new char[n];          

      for (int j = 0; j < chars.length; j++) {
        charArray[j] = chars[j] == '0' ? '+' : '*';
      }
      //System.out.println(charArray);
      for(char c : charArray){
        op_count++;

        if(firstRun == true){
          sum = numbers.get(0);
          numbers.remove(0);
          // System.out.println(sum);
        }

        if (!numbers.isEmpty()){
          if (c == '+') {
            sum += numbers.get(0);
          } else if (c == '*') {
            sum *= numbers.get(0);
          }
          numbers.remove(0);
        }

        firstRun = false;
        //System.out.println(sum);

        if(sum == target && op_count == n){
          int count_print_op = 0;
          System.out.print("L ");
          for(int r = 0; r < temp_array.size(); r++){
            System.out.print(temp_array.get(r) + " ");
            if(count_print_op == n){
              break;
            }
            System.out.print(charArray[count_print_op] + " ");
            count_print_op++;
          }
          System.out.print("\n");
          return;
        }
        if(op_count == n && sum != target){
          firstRun = true;
          sum = 0;
          op_count = 0;
          for(int e = 0; e < temp_array.size(); e++){
            numbers.add(e, temp_array.get(e));
          }
        }
      }          
    }
    System.out.println("L is impossible");
  }
}
```

Is there a faster to way to reach a similar conclusion?

Comment: There is so much code in here. Try to isolate the part that you want to state your question about.

Comment: I feel that without someone actually running and studying your code, it might not be possible to really figure out what it is doing (or trying to do). Can you update the question to include a description about what you are trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved in O(NK²) using the Dynamic Programming paradigm, where K is the maximum possible value for the goal target. This is not that good and maybe there is a faster algorithm, but it's still a lot better than the O(2^N) brute force solution.

First let's define a recurrence to solve the problem: let G be the goal value and f(i,j,k) be a function that returns:

- 1 if we can reach the value G-j-k using only elements from index i and onwards
- 0 otherwise

We are going to use j as an accumulator that holds the current total sum and k as an accumulator that holds the total product of the current chain of multiplications, you will understand it soon.

The base cases for the recurrence are:

- f(N,x,y) = 1 if x+y = G (we have used every element and reached our goal)
- f(N,x,y) = 0 otherwise
- f(i,x,y) = 0 i != N and x+y >= G (we have exceeded the goal before using every element)

For other i values we can define the recurrence as:

- f(i,j,k) = max( f(i+1,j+k,v[i]) , f(i+1,j,k*v[i]) )

The first function call inside max() means that we will put a "+" sign before the current index, so our current multiplication chain is broken and we have to add its total product to the current sum, so the second parameter is j+k, and since we are starting a new multiplication chain right now, it's total product is exactly v[i].

The second function call inside max() means that we will put a "*" sign before the current index, so our current multiplication chain is still going on, so the second parameter remains j, and the third parameter will become k * v[i].

What we want is the value of f(0,0,0) (we haven't used any elements, and our current accumulated sums are equal to 0). f(0,0,0) equals 1 if and only if there is a solution for the problem, so the problem is solved. Now let's go back to the recurrence and fix a detail: when we run f(0,0,0), the value of k*v[i] will be 0 no matter the value of v[i], so we have to add a special check when we are computing the answer for i = 0, and the final recurrence will look like this:

- f(i,j,k) = max( f(i+1,j+k,v[i]) , f(i+1,j,(i==0?v[i]:k*v[i])) )

Finally, we apply the memoization/dynamic programming paradigm to optimize the calculation of the recurrence. During the execution of the algorithm, we will keep track of every calculated state so when this state is called again by another recursive call we just return the stored value instead of computing its whole recursion tree again. Don't forget to do this or your solution is going to be as slow as a brute force solution (or even worse) due to recalculation of subproblems. If you need some resources on DP, you can start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming